# Win32 Listview Tilemode Interactable Item Space Question

Tags: c++, listview, winapi

When custom painting a listview item in tileview, returning CDRF_SKIPDEFAULT during CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT enlarges the interactable rect of the item to the size of the actual item (i.e. the size received from ListView_GetItemRect(LVIR_BOUNDS)) instead of only the size of icon+label. How and why does this happen exactly? I couldn't find a clear answer in the docs or on the web. I mean, shouldn't handling custom paint only affect the painting of the item and not the way you interact with it?

Codesample:

```
::NMLVCUSTOMDRAW* pNMCustomDraw = reinterpret_cast<NMLVCUSTOMDRAW*>(pNMHDR);

switch (pNMCustomDraw->nmcd.dwDrawStage)
{

    // Before the painting cycle begins. 
    case CDDS_PREPAINT:
    {

        return CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW;

    }

    // Before an item is drawn.
    case CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT:
    {

        return CDRF_SKIPDEFAULT;
        
    }
    
}
```

Visual representation of the question:

[image]

Comment: Could you show a mini, complete and reproducible sample for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The line `case CDDS_ITEM | CDDS_PREPAINT` is checking the result value of "or'ing" `CDDS_ITEM | CDDS_PREPAINT`. plus, you already checked `CDDS_PREPAINT` above. Shouldn't it be `CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT` ?

It should be like this, probably:

```
switch (pNMCustomDraw->nmcd.dwDrawStage)
{

    // Before the painting cycle begins. 
    case CDDS_PREPAINT:
    {
        return CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW;

    }

    // Before an item is drawn.
    case CDDS_ITEM: // fall through
    case CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT:
    {

        return CDRF_SKIPDEFAULT;
        
    }
}
```

Plus, MSDN states that:

> CDRF_SKIPDEFAULT The application drew the item manually. The control
> will not draw the item. This occurs when dwDrawStage equals
> CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT.

in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/nm-customdraw-list-view

check here as well (MSDN):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/ns-commctrl-nmcustomdraw

Try that :). And don't forget to add breaks if needed after cases. Greetings

Comment: Hey I've changed it to CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT in the main post thanks. Already checked that article out, but I still don't understand why the item its interaction rect increases when returning CDRF_SKIPDEFAULT.

Comment: Add sub subitems too "case CDDS_SUBITEM | CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT:"  and return the same value as in CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT